# Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorpdf

I am new to asp.net mvc 4.

I have done a simple application using RazorPDF.

Application is to display a normal page in PDF format.
I have created a new application  and it is running fine .But the same thing when i am implementing in my project it is not working and giving the error **as Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'.**

I researched about this and found the concept that why it is displaying this error , as bcoz while installing the RazorPDF it is not installing the HtmlParser inside iTextSharp.

The point I am not getting is if I am doing the same thing in newly application it is installing everything and the code is working fine,if the same i am doing in my project it is not installing all the things through i ma getting this error.

Code is working fine ,no doubt in that.The problem is while installing the RazorPDF
  in my project it is not installing all the 9 subpackages inside the iTextSharp(HtmlEncoder,HtmlTags,HtmlUtilities,WebColors,HtmlParser,Markup,ITextmyHtmlHandler,HtmlWriter,HtmlTagMap) ,it is installing only 4 subpackages(HtmlEncoder,HtmlTags,HtmlUtilities,WebColors).

As HtmlParser have not installed it is displaying this problem ?
Do anyone have knowledge in this (RazorPDF).Can any1 help me out to solve this problem ?

**Coding**
Controller

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using pdf.Models;
 namespace pdf.Controllers
  {
   public class StudentsController : Controller
     {
         public ActionResult Index()
        {
          var studentMarks = new List<MarksCard>()
           {
                        new MarksCard(){ RollNo = 101, Subject = "C#",FullMarks = 100, Obtained = 90},
                        new MarksCard() {RollNo = 101, Subject = "asp.net", FullMarks = 100, Obtained = 80},
                        new MarksCard() {RollNo = 101, Subject = "MVC", FullMarks = 100,Obtained = 100},
                        new MarksCard() {RollNo = 101, Subject = "SQL Server", FullMarks = 100, Obtained = 75},
            };
            return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(studentMarks, "Index");
         } 
   }
 }
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace pdf.Models
  {
    public class MarksCard
     {
        public int RollNo
         {
           get;
           set;
         }
        public string Subject
        {
         get;
         set;
        }
      public int FullMarks
        {
         get;
         set;
       }
     public int Obtained { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<pdf.Models.MarksCard>
  @{
    Layout = null;
   }
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <body>
     <table border="1" width='500' bordercolor="RED"><tr><td colspan="3" bgcolor="LightGreen"  
            align="center" valign="top">
         SSLC Marks Sheet 2013</td></tr><tr><td>
          @{ var rollNumber = Model.Select(z => z.RollNo).Take(1).ToArray();}
          Riyaz Akhter<br />RollNo:@rollNumber[0]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td bgcolor="lightblue">@Html.DisplayNameFor(moel => moel.Subject)</td>
         <td bgcolor="lightblue">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullMarks)</td>
        <td bgcolor="lightblue">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Obtained)</td></tr>
        @{
          int total = 0;
        }
       @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
          <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)</td>
              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullMarks)</td>
              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Obtained)</td>
             </tr>total += item.Obtained;
       }
      <tr><td>
         </td>
          <td>
             <strong><font color="GREEN">Total</font></strong>
           </td>
         <td>@total</td></tr>
       </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this?:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1925729.aspx?how+to+create+pdf+file+using+razor+pdf

I believe it is what you were looking for.